# react native update value of input on click of button and placeholder

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to fetch latitiude and longitude on a button click and set it to TextInput. The issue with below code is the placeholder is always *undefined*.

I tried removing the value attribute, in that case the placeholder is visible but then I am unable to set the location. How can i make the placeholder visible till the location is fetched and then once location is fetched set the value to latitude.

I guess I m not using the setLatLong correctly. can we use useRef to set the values correctly.

```
<TextInput
  style={{
      borderBottomColor: "black",
      borderBottomWidth: 2,
      color: "black",
    }}
  placeholder={"Longitude"}
  placeholderTextColor="blue"
  editable={false}
  textAlign="left"
  ref={longRef}
  value={latLong["latitude"] + ""}
/>
```

complete code is as follows

```
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

import RNLocation from "react-native-location";

RNLocation.configure({ distanceFilter: null });

const getLocation = () => {
  let latRef = React.createRef();
  let longRef = React.createRef();
  let latitude;
  let longitude;

  let [latLong, setLatLong] = useState({});

  const subscribeLocation = () => {
    RNLocation.requestPermission({
      ios: "whenInUse", // or 'always'
      android: {
        detail: "coarse", // or 'fine'
        rationale: {
          title: "We need to access your location",
          message: "We use your location to show where you are on the map",
          buttonPositive: "OK",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        },
      },
    })
      .then((granted) => {
        console.log("Permission Granted: " + granted);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  subscribeLocation();

  const fetchLocation = () => {
    if (RNLocation.getCurrentPermission()) {
      RNLocation.getLatestLocation({
        timeout: 60000,
      }).then((location) => {
        **setLatLong(location)**
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.locationContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            borderBottomColor: "black",
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
            color: "black",
          }}
          placeholder={"Latitude"}
          placeholderTextColor="blue"
          editable={false}
          textAlign="left"
          ref={latRef}
          // value={latitude}
          value={latLong["latitude"] + ""}
        />

        <TextInput
          style={{
            borderBottomColor: "black",
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
            color: "black",
          }}
          placeholder={"Longitude"}
          placeholderTextColor="blue"
          editable={false}
          textAlign="left"
          ref={longRef}
          //  value=''
          value={latLong["latitude"] + ""}
        />

        <View style={styles.touchButton}>
          <Button
            title="Get Location"
            color="red"
            onPress={async () => {
              console.log("Press");
              await fetchLocation();
              // loci  = await fetchLocation()
              // setLatLong(loci)
              // console.log("Locii set")
              // console.log("Lociiiiii " +loci["longitude"])
              // longRef = loci["longitude"]
              // latRef = loci["latitude"]
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.editIdContiner}>
        <View style={styles.touchButton}>
          <Button
            title="Get CSP Details"
            color="red"
            onPress={() => {
              console.log("Hiii");
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
  },

  locationContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignContent: "center",
  },

  editIdContiner: {
    width: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignContent: "center",
  },

  touchButton: {
    width: "100%",
    color: "grey",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default getLocation;
```

Comment: what does the reponse look like inside `fetchLocation`?? Is it an object or a string?? I am talking about the `location` variable inside `fetchLocation` function

Comment: Try to `console.log(location)` before `setLatLong(location)`

Comment: According to your implementation.. Your response or I should say `location` should look like this ---> `{  latitude: "some data", longitude: ''some data here" }`

Comment: Check out [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/textinput-update-example) Snack to see how to update the value in the field after performing `fetch` request.

Comment: @KartikeyVaish response is object with latitude and longitude

Comment: Check the Snack above.

Comment: @KartikeyVaish thank you so much. It worked. can you pls post that as answer. Also if you can bit explain where I was missing the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main approach is that..

According to the `state` variable. The Value should always be an `Object` containing two key-value pairs as shown below

Example Response -

```
{
   'latitude': "some value",
   'longitude': "some value",
{
```

This is because the `value` prop provided to the `TextInput` component displays `latLong["latitude"]  + ''`. So, if we don't pass a correct object in the state..It will show `undefined`.

So whenever you `fetch` something then if you want to update the `state` then you must ensure that the response is of the above type..

[This](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/textinput-update-example) snack shows how to update the TextField value after `fetching` it from the server.